# Evaluate the following trigonometric integral with exponential function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, complex-analysis, trigonometric-integrals

> Find the value of $$\int_0^\pi\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{e}^{\cos\left(x\right)}}\cos\left(\sin\left(x\right)\right)\cos\left(\mathrm{e}^x\sin\left(\sin\left(x\right)\right)\right)dx$$

How to solve this integral$?$ I tried using $u=\sin x$ substitution but it unnecessary made the problem more complicated, for instance $e^x$ will now be $e^{\arcsin u}.$ I also tried to calculate it with integral calculator but it failed. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where did you catch the monster ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici from a local chat group...it was posted a few days ago..ig a month...but nobody could solve it... including me

Comment: We at least have [an approximate value](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+from+0+to+pi+of+e%5E%28e%5Ecos+x%29+cos%28sin%28x%29%29+cos%28e%5Ex+sin%28sin%28x%29%29%29) of it, $6.96534$. It's close to $10 \ln(2)$ but that does not mean anything...

Comment: @BrunoB maybe you're right that $10\ln2$ doesn't mean anything..but I in my wildest dreams can never think of this analogy

Comment: A good approximation is $$\frac{25}{2} \sqrt{\sqrt[4]{7}-\sqrt[4]{3}}$$ in an absolute error of $3.64\times 10^{-7}$

Comment: It the integral were $\int_{0}^{\pi} e^{e^{ \cos(x)} \cos(\sin x)} \cos\left(e^{\cos(x)} \sin(\sin x) \right)\, \mathrm d x$, the value would be $\pi e$ since the integrand is the real part of $e^{e^{e^{ix}}}$.

Comment: @RandomVariable great observation!!!...can you pls tell how did you extract the real part?....I know $e^{ix}$ has the real part $\cos x$...but what will we do here?

Comment: $$ \begin{align} e^{e^{e^{ix}}}=e^{e^{cos(x) + i \sin(x)}}  &=  e^{e^{\cos x}\left(\cos(\sin x) + i \sin (\sin x) \right)} \\ &= e^{e^{\cos x} \cos(\sin x)} \left(\cos(e^{ \cos x} \sin (\sin x))+ i \sin (e^{\cos x} \sin (\sin x)) \right) \end{align}   $$

Comment: And $$\Re \int_{0}^{\pi} e^{e^{e^{ix}}} \, \mathrm dx = \frac{1}{2} \, \Re \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{e^{e^{ix}}} \, \mathrm dx = \frac{1}{2} \, \Re \int_{|z|=1} \frac{e^{e^{z}}}{iz} \, \mathrm dz = \frac{1}{2} \, \Re \, \frac{2 \pi i }{i} \,  \operatorname{Res} \left[\frac{e^{e^{z}}}{z}, 0 \right] = \pi e.$$

Comment: Do you know if there is a closed form?

Comment: @Accelerator no I don't...

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad Where'd you get this, Great question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on @Random Variable's comment, spent quite some time trying to understand the actual question;

$$I=\int_0^\pi\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{e}^{\cos\left(x\right)}}\cos\left(\sin\left(x\right)\right)\cos\left(\mathrm{e}^x\sin\left(\sin\left(x\right)\right)\right)dx$$

But it is not ending nicely, however if it were;

$$\int_0^\pi e^{e^{cosx}cos(sinx)}cos(e^{cosx}sin(sinx))\,dx$$

The integral can be evaluated and gives a nice answer. (I have a feeling that this was the actual question you intended to ask)

$$I=Re\left[\int_0^\pi e^{e^{cosx}cos(sinx)}e^{ie^{cosx}sin(sinx)}\,dx\right]$$

$$I=Re\left[\int_0^\pi e^{e^{cosx}(cos(sinx)+isin(sinx)}\,dx\right]$$

$$I=Re\left[\int_0^\pi e^{e^{cosx}ie^{sinx}}\,dx\right]$$

$$I=Re\left[\int_0^\pi e^{e^{cosx}+i{sinx}}\,dx\right]$$

$$I=Re\left[\int_0^\pi e^{e^{e^{ix}}}\,dx\right]$$

$$I=Re\left[\int_0^\pi \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(e^{e^{ix}})^n}{n!}\,dx\right]$$

$$I=Re\left[\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!} \int_0^{\pi}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(ne^{ix})^k}{k!}\,dx\right]$$

$$I=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(n)^k}{k!}\int_0^{\pi} cos(kx) \,dx$$

$$I=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(n)^k}{k!} \frac{sin{\pi k}}{k}$$

$$I=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}\left[\pi+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(n)^k}{k!} \frac{sin{\pi k}}{k} \right]$$
$$I=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}\left[\pi\right]=\pi e $$

> Used Euler's Formula and expansion for $e^x$